# Is there a meaningful measure of the probability for a finite group to be commutative?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Of course the probability will depend on the measure put on the groups, and it is trivial to define many such measures if they do not have to be useful or significant in any way!  But is there such a measure that is actually useful?  Or are there several useful ones?

Comment: Do you mean "Given a specific finite group, what is the probability of a randomly-chosen pair of elements commuting?" or "Given a randomly-chosen group of order $n$, what is the probability that the group is abelian?"

Comment: @mweiss In those terms: "Given a randomly chosen finite group, what is the probability that group is abelian?"

Comment: Funny that that interpretation of the question didn't even occur to me. :)

Comment: If you are asking what proportion of groups of order at most $n$ are commutative, then this will certainly tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That makes sense.  Is there a quick heuristic to see it?

Comment: There are less than $n$ abelian groups  of order $n$, but the total number of groups of order $p^k$ for prime $p$ is about $p^{2k^3/27}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the posted question is no: there is no useful notion of probability over all finite groups for measuring the commutative groups.

Maybe if I were more used to finite structures I would have asked about probability for any finite order $n$ in the first place, rather than for all finite groups.

But certainly, for this question of commutative groups, the asymptotics in the order $n$ show the proportion of Abelian groups is vanishingly small.  So there is no interest in assigning a probability measure on all finite groups for this purpose.